# JQuery .hide & .show occupy space even is hide

Tags: jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/andersonkoh/y6s9esnh/2/embed/"></script>
```

As you can see, when I select request then **.show my** **.request-row** but it goes down and when I right click > Inspect in browser it show that **.enquiry-row** is hidden but occupy the space. How do I make it in the same line without pushing it go down?

Comment: Try remove the padding and margin for enquiry-row

Comment: Helo @MrHery, Subash solve my problem and he explain clearly. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hide this itself `<div class="col col-6">` rather than hidding element which is inside the `<div class="col col-6"><div id="enquiry-row" style="display:none;"></div></div>`, in your case `class="col col-6"` this take the space of the element.

So it should like this `<div class="col col-6" id="enquiry-row" style="display:none;"><div></div></div>`.

Here is the **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y6s9esnh/5/)**

Comment: Helo @Subash. You solve my problem. Thank you very much. I want to ask 1 more thing. If I'm going to .show when I'm select second option which is "Request" and I want to .hide the e-feedback-form which is the last result from "Enquiry". 

This is what i did:
  `$('#selectOptions').on('change',function(){
      if( $(this).val()==="option-2"){
      $("#request-row").show(), $(".e-feedback-form-group").hide()
      }
      else{
      $("#request-row").hide()
      }
  });`

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Helo. I solve it. I just group the enquiry result into `<div id="enquiry-results"></div>` and the script will be 
  `$('#selectOptions').on('change',function(){
      if( $(this).val()==="option-2"){
      $("#request-row").show()
       $("#enquiry-results").hide()
      }
      else{
      $("#request-row").hide()
      }
  });`,  of course I also add `$("#enquiry-results").show()` to show back when `Enquiry` is selected!